# accessibilityPerformEscape does not dismiss UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to show a `UIAlertContoller` and dismiss it when VoiceOver user performs a scrub gesture:

```
override func accessibilityPerformMagicTap() -> Bool {
        showPopup()
        return true
    }

    override func accessibilityPerformEscape() -> Bool {
        print("close")
        return true
    }

    func showPopup(){
        baseAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Popup", message: "Choose an option", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "method 1", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("one")
        }

        let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "method 2", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("two")
        }

        let thirdAction = UIAlertAction(title: "method 3", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("three")
        }

        let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Destructive) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            print("close")
            self.accessibilityPerformEscape()
        }

        baseAlert.addAction(firstAction)
        baseAlert.addAction(secondAction)
        baseAlert.addAction(thirdAction)
            baseAlert.addAction(closeAction)

        baseAlert.accessibilityHint = "Pop menu"
        presentViewController(baseAlert, animated: true, completion:
            {
                    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        )


    }
```

The above code shows the `UIAlertController` and when I perform scrub gesture it does not react to it, but when the alert is not shown or dismissed escape gesture works.

Comment: Have you found out a solution for your question at the time you could share with us, please? 

Comment: It was a long time ago, i don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the code to dismiss your UIAlertController in `accessibilityPerformEscape()`, returning `true` is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your scrub gesture works when there's no alert view because you are in a controller *(navigation controller ???)* that natively takes into account this VoiceOver gesture.

However, you were following the right method for you alert view by overriding the `accessibilityPerformEscape` method : the problem dealt with its 'empty' implementation that could be adjusted according to this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52505599/3825084) by adding a `dismiss` order.