# VoiceOver Z gesture won't trigger when UIAlertController is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to use the Z gesture to dismiss a UIAlertController. I have a very simple app. It has a single view with 1 button. Tapping the button presents an alert. I have implemented

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityPerformEscape {
    NSLog(@"Z gesture");
    return YES;
}
```

With VoiceOver on, scrubbing the screen prints out "Z gesture," but when I press the button and the alert is visible, scrubbing the screen does nothing, the method is not called and nothing is printed. What do I have to do to get this to function while the alert is on screen?

Thanks...

Comment: This [GitHub thread](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/3661#issuecomment-404301151) may help. Looks like you need the accessibility delegate method to be implemented in the custom view controller itself—in this case presumably the UIAlertController instance.

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired result on your alert view thanks to the scrub gesture, override `accessibilityPerformEscape()` in the alert view itself.

A solution could be to implement this override in an UIView extension as follows :

```
extension UIView {

override open func accessibilityPerformEscape() -> Bool {

    if let myViewController = self.findMyViewController() as? UIAlertController {

        myViewController.dismiss(animated: true,
                                 completion: nil)
    }
    return true
}


private func findMyViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
        return nextResponder
    } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
        return nextResponder.findMyViewController()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

}
```

The code is short enough to be understood without further explanation. If it's not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

The function `findMyViewController` has been found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-the-view-controller-responsible-for-a-view).

Comment: Is there no way to attach the gesture handler to an alert without modifying UIView like that?

Comment: @GrantNeufeld: this is just an example of implementation I found interesting. I think you can override the 'accessibilityPerformEscape' in a subclass of 'UIAlertController'  you create as well.

Comment: It is interesting that this needs to be overridden for a standard `UIAlertController`. Apple's documentation says: 

'Dismiss an alert or return to the previous screen: Two-finger scrub (move two fingers back and forth three times quickly, making a “z”)'

But they neglect to provide a default implementation? https://support.apple.com/en-kz/guide/iphone/iph3e2e2281/ios